# seleniumを使ったweb操作で別タブに開いてしまったサイトのurlを取得したい

Tags: python, selenium

seleniumでWebを開いた後，ユーザが操作をすることで開いたページのurlを取得しようとしました．

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://kakolog.jp/q/')
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(browser.current_url)
```

上のコードでWebを開いた後各スレッドをクリックすると，別のタブでページを開かれ，そのページのurlを取得できませんでした．

どうすればこのurlを取得できますか?

Comment: この辺の記事でそれは難しそうな感じですが何か参考になるかもしれません。[How can I reconnect to the browser opened by webdriver with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47861813/9014308), [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8344776/9014308), [Re-using existing browser session in selenium](https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/), [How to connect Selenium to an existing browser that was opened manually?](https://cosmocode.io/how-to-connect-selenium-to-an-existing-browser-that-was-opened-manually/)

Answer (score 2):

リンク先のURLを取得することが目的であれば、クリックせずに`<a target="_blank" ... href="URL">`から`href`を直接抽出することができます。
(サンプルコードの「# 1.エレメントから最初のアンカーを読み取り、URLを取得する」をご参照ください)
そこから[`driver.get`](https://www.seleniumqref.com/api/python/window_set/Python_get.html)でポップアップせずに遷移する処理が可能です。

また、クリック後にポップアップしたタブのURL取得や操作をする場合は、`driver.switch_to.window`で任意のタブをアクティブにすることで対応可能です。
(サンプルコードの「# 2.ポップアップタブをアクティブ化し、アクティブタブのURLを取得する」をご参照ください)

参考資料: [How to get the URL "about:blank" from empty tab using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55650317)

**サンプルコード：**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
url='https://kakolog.jp/q/'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

# 先頭の 'boxContainer item' エレメントを取得
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('boxContainer.item')
# 1.エレメントから最初のアンカーを読み取り、URLを取得する
anchor = element.find_element_by_class_name('link')
print(anchor.get_attribute('href'))

# メインタブのウィンドウハンドルを保持しておく
main_tab = driver.current_window_handle

# アンカーをクリックしてポップアップ
anchor.click()
time.sleep(1)

# 2.ポップアップタブをアクティブ化し、アクティブタブのURLを取得する
new_tab = [x for x in driver.window_handles if x != main_tab][0]
driver.switch_to.window(new_tab)
print(driver.current_url)
time.sleep(1)

# アクティブタブを閉じる
driver.close()
time.sleep(1)
```